# My keyboard won't allow me to make a new paragraph.

Tags: android

So I've been talking to people on G+ for a few months and I always pressed this button in the lower right corner to move the text cursor make a new paragraph. Recently, I've been noticing when I go to respond to someone, and I go to do the same thing, the keyboard just goes away. I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: This question is not about programming and thus does not belong on StackOverflow. However, there should be an option called **"Enter is send"** in your keyboard setting that you can manipulate. Otherwise, resort to Google.

Comment: You might like https://android.stackexchange.com/